# Kinds of isometries preserving the curvature tensor

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, curvature

We talked about isometries /local isometries and linear isometries in the lecture, but unfortunately we did not say when the isometry preserves the curvature tensor or sectional curvature.

First I am wondering: Is preserving the sectional curvature equivalent to preserving the whole curvature tensor?

A linear isometry $L :T_pM \rightarrow T_qN$ is defined as

$$g_q(LV,LV) = g_p(V,V).$$

Such a map does not generally preserve sectional curvature, as we can always find such a map between two tangent spaces of two Riemannian manifolds, but clearly the curvature tensors can be different. So such a map does not generally preserve the curvature tensor.

A local isometry is a local diffeomorphism $\phi: U \subset M \rightarrow V,$ where $V$ is a subset of $N$  such that $D \phi$ is a linear isometry.

Now, one could ask if this mean that $$D \phi(R_p(V,W)(X))= R_{\phi(p)}(D \phi (V),D\phi(W))(D\phi(X))$$ holds? I don't think so cause the polar map 
$$\phi = exp_{q,N} \circ L \circ \exp_{p,M}^{-1}$$ can be always defined on two manifolds locally with respect to the two appropriate exponential maps. But still two manifolds do not need to have the same curvature tensor.

Hence, my second question is: Is it really true that only global isometries preserve curvature (both sectional curv. and the curvature tensor) on manifolds in general?

Comment: Local isometries preserve everything that is constructed from the metric.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez but can't I always define the polar map as a local isometry between two manifolds? You take a sufficiently small (normal neighbourhood) on each manifold and then you can define the local isometry $\phi = exp_{q,N} \circ L \circ \exp_{p,M}^{-1}$

Comment: What happens if you try to do that in the concrete case where you have a point in the sphere and one on the (flat)  plane?

Comment: Okay, let's fix two tangent spaces on Riemannian manifolds $M$ and $N$. I call them $T_pM$ and $T_q N$ now. Then you can define according to linear algebra a linear isometry $L: T_pM \rightarrow T_qN.$ Now consider the exponential maps $exp_{q,N}: V \subset T_qN \rightarrow N$ and $exp_{p,M}: U \subset T_pM \rightarrow M$ where $V,U$ are sufficiently small. Then the $\phi$ I defined in the previous comment should be a local isometry or not?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I see your point. The classical Theorema egregrium tells us that such a map should not exist between the sphere and the plane, but I currently don't see where it fails.

Comment: I think you are confused between the ideas of  a "local isometry" and (this is not standard since its not a useful thing to talk about) an isometry at a point. The exponential map preserves the inner product at the point its based around, and does essentially the best possible job at approximating it locally, but it is not a local isometry. Local isometry means that the metric tensor is preserved perfectly in an open region of the point.